# SharePoint Online Document ID (generated by Document ID feature) indexing not happen immediately after Document ID generated?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-id

Upon uploading document, Document ID service generates Document ID. However if we try to open using the Document ID immediately, it gives error as File Not Found. But after some seconds, it opens the document. Is there anyway to improve/speedup, such that, after uploading document, immediately if we open the document using Document ID link it should open?

Comment: You're probably best talking to Microsoft support regarding this. We don't have any access to the server side resources/services that could theoretically speed up the indexing.

Comment: FYI the DocID is generated by search indexing. A document that hasn't been indexed won't have a DocID.

Comment: Yes we know. But our scenario is, we want to access the document immediately using the DOC ID after uploading into library.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following article, which may be helpful to you！
[Enable and configure unique Document IDs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-and-configure-unique-document-ids-ea7fee86-bd6f-4cc8-9365-8086e794c984#__toc286303372)

---

**If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.**

Comment: Is there any update on this thread? Comment here if you still need any help.